A post-apocalyptic novel with a mutant girl covered with fur
I read this post-apocalyptic novel about 20 years ago. I am positive that I read it in French, in a paperback. But it might well have been a translation, quite possibly from English.
At the beginning, the main character lives in a dystopia, ruled by a dictator who controls people by sending them dreams. IIRC, the dictator thus convinces everyone in his domain, for instance, to eat only canned food ("boîtes de conserves"), whenever possible. But he does not control his borders. So after meeting a mutant young girl, covered with fur, the main character leaves on a road trip with her. They reach other places, still post-apocalyptic but in different ways.
It gets very complicated, weirder and weirder. I don't remember how it ends.

Amnesia Moon (1995) by Jonathan Lethem.
Summary from nooSFere, which contains more matches than Wikipedia's summary (most of the translation courtesy of DeepL):

Does anyone remember?
There's general amnesia in Hatfork and Little America, in the Wyoming desert. People think they remember a catastrophe that happened a few years ago. But when exactly?
What if it's just a legend? Or a gigantic scam cooked up by Kellogg to justify food rationing? Kellogg, the local dictator who imposes his law by controlling the nocturnal dreams of his fellow citizens...
For Chaos, there's only one way to find out: flee and go elsewhere.
A long journey in search of his own identity, in the company of Melinda, a little girl covered in hair, will lead him to the heart of an open-air labyrinth in a devastated San Francisco.
A dreamlike journey into Jonathan Lethem's rich imagination: zany and bizarrely logical, baffling and hilarious... In short, jubilant!


Found with the Google query dictateur reves site:noosfere.org (dictator dreams site:noosfere.org).

Yes, this is the one. The French title was "Un homme nommé Chaos"
